# Low Seg2Cat Not showing all entries

Tags: low-seg2cat

I am using Low Seg2Cat [here](http://reapvalue.ehclients.com/what-we-do/category/renewable-energy) and there are three entries with the Renewable Energy category. However, only one of them is displaying.

Here is the code I am using:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="what_we_do" category="{segment_3_category_id}" }
                            <div class="project">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <img src="{project_thumbnail}" alt="{title}" >
                                    </div>
                                    <h3><a href="/what-we-do/project/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3>
                                    <p>{project_summary} <a href="/what-we-do/project/{url_title}">More...</a></p>
                            </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can't see what I might be missing here. Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does it work if you set dynamic="no"?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes that solves the problem. Thanks.